# WPF/FormsControl Integration Warnings

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

Using the thecnique shown here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx

I created 2 projects, 
1 project for the forms control with Microsoft RDP Client Control - version 9
And another WPF project where I use the WPF WindowsFormsHost Control to host the RDP Client from the previous project.

In the WPF project a referenced the assemblies AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll and the Interop.MSTSCLib.dll, these assemblies are generated when adding the RDP COM Component (in project 1 - the forms control with Microsoft RDP Client Control - version 9).

Everything appears to working fine in the WPF project I can connect to other machines using RDP, but I have 2 problems...

1 - Interop.MSTSCLib.dll reference is never copy to the debug folder, I have to manually copy it or use the Build Events to xcopy it... (This is not a big deal...)

2 - The second problem is worse, when I compile the FormsControl prokject I get a lot of warnings like:

```
Warning     
    Processing COM reference "MSTSCLib" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mstscax.dll". At least one of the arguments for 'MsRdpClient9.get_UIParentWindowHandle' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler. 
    Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate.
```

In the WPF project I also get lots of Warnings like

```
1>  COM Reference 'MSTSCLib' is the interop assembly for ActiveX control 'AxMSTSCLib' but was marked to be linked by the compiler with the /link flag. This COM reference will be treated as a reference and will not be linked.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2399,5): warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference "MSTSCLib" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mstscax.dll". At least one of the arguments for 'MsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting.get_UIParentWindowHandle' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2399,5): warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference "MSTSCLib" from path "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mstscax.dll". At least one of the arguments for 'MsRdpClient8.get_UIParentWindowHandle' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate.
```

How to solve these and what cautions should I worry about.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need host Winform in WPF, and need remove warnings?

Comment: According with research ActiveX control 'AxMSTSCLib' is not supported in WPF controls... Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Then why need AxMSTSCLib

Comment: When I say not supported, I mean directly imported to WPF, so I created in a separated project and then imported to a WindowsFormsHost in WPF similar to the linkl that I provided in the description